# C# потоки. Как правильно закрыть поток в состоянии "Aborted"

Tags: c#, многопоточность

На форме (WinForms) есть кнопка, по нажатию на которую стартует отдельный поток. Если во время его выполнения еще раз нажать эту кнопку, то его работа должна завершаться. Как правильно реализовать эту простую логику в данном коде?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button ClickedButton = (Button)sender;
       //класс "singleton" в котором выполняется поток (для удобства)
       FormAssistent.FormAssistentWorker worker = FormAssistent.FormAssistentWorker.getInstance();
       //если поток еще не завершился, вызываем Abort()...так правильно?
       if (!worker.isComplete())
       { 
           worker.Abort();
           return;
       }  
        //а этот метод стартует поток (Parameters здесь опущен для краткости)  
        worker.Arrange(Parameters);

    }

  //класс "FormAssistentWorker" - singleton, обертка над потоком
  public class FormAssistentWorker
    {
        //singleton
        private static FormAssistentWorker instance;                          
        //Поток для выполнения расстановки форм      
        private Thread FormAssistentThread;

        private FormAssistentWorker()
        {
            FormAssistentThread = getFormAssistentThread();
        }

        public static FormAssistentWorker getInstance()
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new FormAssistentWorker();
            return instance;
        }

        public void Arrange(ArrangeParameters param)
        {
            Thread workThread = getFormAssistentThread();
            //вот тут возникает System.Threading.ThreadStateException
            //так как поток в состоянии "Aborted". Как это исправить? 
            //Нужно обрабатывать это состояние в getFormAssistentThread()?
            workThread.Start(param);

        }

        public bool isComplete()
        {
            return !(FormAssistentThread.IsAlive);
        }

        public void Abort()
        {
            if (FormAssistentThread != null)
            FormAssistentThread.Abort();
        }

        private Thread getFormAssistentThread()
        {

            if (FormAssistentThread == null)
            {
                FormAssistentThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Work));
            }

            if (FormAssistentThread.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Running)
            {
                FormAssistentThread.Join();
            }

            if (FormAssistentThread.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped)
            {
                FormAssistentThread.Abort();
                FormAssistentThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Work));
            }

            return FormAssistentThread;
        }

        private void Work(object ArrangeParam)
        {
            ArrangeParameters parameters = (ArrangeParameters)ArrangeParam;
            parameters.formAssistent.Arrange(parameters);   
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Могу сказать как сделать это с потоками Task и CancellationToken

```
    CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = cancelTokenSource.Token;

    Task task = new Task(() =>
    {
        //Work
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
          //cancel
          return;
        }
        //Work
    });
    task.Start();

    //повторное нажатие кнопки вызывает
    cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
```

Comment: Да, в моем случае можно было применить классы CancellationTokenSource. Все работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вы делаете неправильно. `Thread.Abort` — очень опасная функция, использовать её не следует. Для завершения задания код этого задания должен *сотрудничать*, то есть, завершаться сам тогда, когда его об этом попросят.

Простейшее решение — с volatile-флагом типа `bool`, но лучше использовать специально предназначенный для таких целей `CancellationToken`.